# Trying to implement text to speech in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, text-to-speech

I ' m trying to implement text to speech in uwp but it's not working .Any help would be appreciated.
Xaml

```
<MediaElement x:Name="textToSpeech" Volume="0.9" />
```

c# code

```
private async void N123tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string speechText = "LearnCounting";
   // var speechText = "LearnCounting";
   var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
   var speechStream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(speechText);
   this.textToSpeech.AutoPlay = true;
   this.textToSpeech.SetSource(speechStream, speechStream.ContentType);
   this.textToSpeech.Play();
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(N123P));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code, but it's working properly for me. Are you sure you're not hearing anything? Maybe it's your machine's volume? Also, make sure your **Tapped** event is really getting triggered. Add breakpoints to make sure it gets triggered.

Hope it helps!

Comment: After placing it works                                                                                await Task.Delay(1000);

Comment: I was thinking that the problem before might be the navigation. Cause it didn't have the time to play the mediaElement, because it quickly navigates, but it worked properly here.

Comment: Anyway, great job :)